# Couchbase N1QL: index and query on array fields

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Platform: Couchbase Server 4.0 beta, Java client 2.1.3

I am looking for something similar to SQL JOIN. For example I have documents of the form where field2 is embedded in the document instead of in a separate table as you would have in a relational DB:

```
    {field1:" ..", field2:[{key:1, ...},{key:3, ...},..],...}.
```

How can I achieve something like this:

```
    select * from bucket where field2.key=3;
```

And how can I index the key, a hypothetical example:

```
    create index idx_key on bucket(field2.key);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you did something like this:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM `your-bucket-here` AS fields
WHERE 
    ANY field IN fields.field2 SATISFIES field.key = 3 END
```

This way as long as one nested array item contains your value, it will be returned.

In terms of creating an index, are you looking to create a secondary index or a primary index?  You could always do something like this:

```
CREATE PRIMARY INDEX index_name ON `your-bucket-name-here` USING GSI;
CREATE INDEX index_name ON `your-bucket-name-here` USING GSI;
```

Let me know how all that goes!

Best,

Comment: Your query works, thanks @Nic. I came up with a different query using UNNEST that also works.   The second part of the question still remains, how do you create a secondary index on field2.key.

Comment: the CREATE INDEX (secondary index) syntax should provide the field in parenthesis like `CREATE INDEX index_name ON bucket(field2) USING GSI;`. So I wonder if you could replace `field2` with `field2.key`, but I'm not sure...

Comment: to check that an index is used, you can use `EXPLAIN SELECT...` (prefixing your statement with EXPLAIN to get the execution plan and look for the index name in there)

Comment: Thanks @Simon for the suggestion. Already tried. Did not work. By the way this is how multikey index looks like in MongoDB.